# Russian numbers (in the thousands)

Tags: перевод, числительные

I've been consulting [the official website of the city of Dushanbe](https://www.dushanbe.tj/ru/rushdi-i-tisodiyot) and found the following interesting passage:

> Согласно данным органов ЗАГС-а с 2005 по 2014 год в городе Душанбе
> зарегистрировано 155720 тысяч новорожденных.

Which Google translates as:

> According to the data of the registry office, from 2005 to 2014,
> 155,720 thousand newborns were registered in the city of Dushanbe.

Most likely, the website only meant "155,720 newborns", but this is not the only time тысяч ("thousand") appears following an already-sufficient decimal number. Is this some  custom in Russian or simply a repeated typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this some custom in Russian or simply a repeated typo?

No. It's clearly an error. It would be an error even if it was a custom, but I can assure you there is no such custom. If you just read the sentence aloud rather than scan it, you'll *have* to say "thousands" twice.

It would be technically correct if there were a decimal point like

> 155,720 тысяч

(`,` is the decimal point in most European languages, including Russian). But this would be rare: if you are spelling out "тысяч", you are typically not interested in precision above a thousand, and it would be `156 тысяч`, often abbreviated to `тыс.`

Comment: @tum_ to be precise, it should have been spelled "сто пятьдесят пять целых, семьсот двадяать тысячных тысяч новорожденных" :)